# Xaml Set SelecteIndex on itemSource updated on combobox

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, itemssource, selectedindex

I want every time my itemssource of my combobox is changed, that the SelectedIndex is set.

I have this so far:

```
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Setter Property="SelectedIndex"
                Value="0"></Setter>
    </Style>
```

It sets the selectedIndex, but only the first time the itemSource is set. When the whole itemSource is changed, it is loaded in the combobox but not selected anymore. At this moment it should select the first item.
Every ItemSource has a binding and I do not want to set the SelectedIndex by code behind.
I want a solution in xaml with maybe a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to disagree with Sheridan - the developer is of course allowed to set the `SelectedIndex` property. However, it is not possible to achieve your goal only within XAML, i.e. by using styles, control templates and triggers. That is because dependency properties have a certain value precedence, e.g. locally set values (by a binding or by the control itself) have greater priority than values that come from a WPF style (that's why your Setter only works once). You can learn more about that at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx

However, besides the possibility to control the selected index from a view model (as Sheridan proposed), there's also the possibility to create e.g. an attached dependency property which is set on the combo box and that looks for changes on the combo boxes' `ItemsSource` property. Your XAML would then look somewhat like this:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBox" l:ComboBoxExtensions.InitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged="0" />
```

Notice that I set the attached dependency property `ComboBoxExtensions.InitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged` to `0`, which means that every time the `ItemsSource` changes, the `SelectedIndex` will be set to 0. The `l:` refers to the local XML namespace (xmlns) that I need to reference to use my custom attached property.

I've implemented the Dependency Property this way:

```cs
public class ComboBoxExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty InitialIndexOnItemsSourceChangedProperty;
    private static readonly IDictionary<ComboBox, BindingSpy<ComboBox, IEnumerable>> ComboBoxToBindingSpiesMapping = new Dictionary<ComboBox, BindingSpy<ComboBox, IEnumerable>>();


    static ComboBoxExtensions()
    {
        InitialIndexOnItemsSourceChangedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("InitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged",
                                                                                       typeof (int?),
                                                                                       typeof (ComboBoxExtensions),
                                                                                       new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnInitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged));
    }

    public static void SetInitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged(ComboBox targetComboBox, int? value)
    {
        if (targetComboBox == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("targetComboBox");

        targetComboBox.SetValue(InitialIndexOnItemsSourceChangedProperty, value);
    }

    public static int? GetInitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged(ComboBox targetComboBox)
    {
        if (targetComboBox == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("targetComboBox");

        return (int?) targetComboBox.GetValue(InitialIndexOnItemsSourceChangedProperty);
    }

    private static void OnInitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var targetComboBox = d as ComboBox;
        if (targetComboBox == null)
            return;

        if ((int?) e.NewValue != null)
        {
            SetInitialIndexIfPossible(targetComboBox);
            EstablishBindingSpy(targetComboBox);
            return;
        }

        ReleaseBindingSpy(targetComboBox);
    }

    private static void EstablishBindingSpy(ComboBox targetComboBox)
    {
        if (ComboBoxToBindingSpiesMapping.ContainsKey(targetComboBox))
            return;

        var bindingSpy = new BindingSpy<ComboBox, IEnumerable>(targetComboBox, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty);
        bindingSpy.TargetValueChanged += OnItemsSourceChanged;
        ComboBoxToBindingSpiesMapping.Add(targetComboBox, bindingSpy);
    }

    private static void ReleaseBindingSpy(ComboBox targetComboBox)
    {
        if (ComboBoxToBindingSpiesMapping.ContainsKey(targetComboBox) == false)
            return;

        var bindingSpy = ComboBoxToBindingSpiesMapping[targetComboBox];
        bindingSpy.ReleaseBinding();
        ComboBoxToBindingSpiesMapping.Remove(targetComboBox);
    }

    private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(BindingSpy<ComboBox, IEnumerable> bindingSpy)
    {
        SetInitialIndexIfPossible(bindingSpy.TargetObject);
    }

    private static void SetInitialIndexIfPossible(ComboBox targetComboBox)
    {
        var initialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged = GetInitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged(targetComboBox);
        if (targetComboBox.ItemsSource != null && initialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged.HasValue)
        {
            targetComboBox.SelectedIndex = initialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

In this class I define the former mentioned attached property. The other important part is the `OnInitialIndexOnItemsSourceChanged` method, which will be called when the attached property is set on a combo box. In there I just determine whether I have to observe the `ItemsSource` property of the combo box or not.

To achieve observation of `ItemsSource`, I use another custom class called `BindingSpy` which establishes a data binding between `ItemsSource` and a custom dependency property of the binding spy because that is the only way that I can recognize if the `ItemsSource` property has changed. Unfortunately, `ComboBox` (respectively `ItemsControl`) does not provide an event that indicates that the source collection has changed. `BindingSpy` is implemented as follows:

```cs
public class BindingSpy<TSource, TValue> : DependencyObject where TSource : DependencyObject
{
    private readonly TSource _targetObject;
    private readonly DependencyProperty _targetProperty;

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("TargetValue",
                                                                                                typeof (TValue),
                                                                                                typeof (BindingSpy<TSource, TValue>),
                                                                                                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, OnTargetValueChanged));

    public BindingSpy(TSource targetObject, DependencyProperty targetProperty)
    {
        if (targetObject == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("targetObject");
        if (targetProperty == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("targetProperty");
        _targetObject = targetObject;
        _targetProperty = targetProperty;

        var binding = new Binding
                      {
                          Source = targetObject,
                          Path = new PropertyPath(targetProperty),
                          Mode = BindingMode.OneWay
                      };
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(this, TargetValueProperty, binding);
    }

    public TValue TargetValue
    {
        get { return (TValue) GetValue(TargetValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TargetValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public TSource TargetObject
    {
        get { return _targetObject; }
    }

    public DependencyProperty TargetProperty
    {
        get { return _targetProperty; }
    }

    public void ReleaseBinding()
    {
        BindingOperations.ClearBinding(this, TargetValueProperty);
    }

    private static void OnTargetValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var bindingSpy = d as BindingSpy<TSource, TValue>;
        if (bindingSpy == null)
            return;

        if (bindingSpy.TargetValueChanged != null)
            bindingSpy.TargetValueChanged(bindingSpy);
    }

    public event Action<BindingSpy<TSource, TValue>> TargetValueChanged;
}
```

As I said before, this class establishes a binding and notifies clients via the `TargetValueChanged` event.

Another way to achieve this is to create a WPF behavior that is part of the Blend SDK. You can find a tutorial for that here: http://wpftutorial.net/Behaviors.html. Basically it's the same pattern as with attached properties.

If you use MVVM, I would definitely suggest that you use Sheridan's solution - but if not, my solution might be more appropriate.

If you have any questions, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The `ComboBox.SelectedIndex` is set by the `ComboBox` itself and not supposed to be set by the developer. You are supposed to data bind an `int` property to it so that you can tell which item is selected and/or select an item from code:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding YourItems}" SelectedIndex="{Binding YourIndex}" />
```

Then in code:

```
int selectedIndex = YourIndex;
```

Or to select the first item for example:

```
YourIndex = 0;
```

To find out more about data binding, please refer to the [Data Binding Overview‎](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN.